# Python: How to sort elements of a set in column value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe, in which one of the column (status) has `set` as a value.

```
                         box_name   scheduled_time                                   status
0                FIN_D1_BATCH_JOB         21:00:00                          {'NOT_STARTED'}
1       FIN_CREDIT_BATCH_PHIL_JOB         01:10:00                            {'COMPLETED'}
2       FIN_CREDIT_BATCH_CAND_JOB         00:30:00                            {'COMPLETED'}
3        FIN_DEBIT_BATCH_PHIL_JOB         01:00:00                            {'COMPLETED'}
4        FIN_DEBIT_BATCH_CAND_JOB         21:00:00                            {'COMPLETED'}
5        FIN_DEBIT_BATCH_RUSS_JOB         01:00:00                            {'COMPLETED'}
6      FIN_DEBIT_EM_OTC_BATCH_JOB         05:00:00                {'RUNNING','NOT_STARTED'}
7               FIN_SIT_BATCH_JOB         11:00:00  {'NOT_STARTED', 'RUNNING', 'COMPLETED'}
```

I need to sort the values of the set, i.e. the dataframe's status column should appear like:

```
                         box_name   scheduled_time                                   status
0                FIN_D1_BATCH_JOB         21:00:00                          {'NOT_STARTED'}
1       FIN_CREDIT_BATCH_PHIL_JOB         01:10:00                            {'COMPLETED'}
2       FIN_CREDIT_BATCH_CAND_JOB         00:30:00                            {'COMPLETED'}
3        FIN_DEBIT_BATCH_PHIL_JOB         01:00:00                            {'COMPLETED'}
4        FIN_DEBIT_BATCH_CAND_JOB         21:00:00                            {'COMPLETED'}
5        FIN_DEBIT_BATCH_RUSS_JOB         01:00:00                            {'COMPLETED'}
6      FIN_DEBIT_EM_OTC_BATCH_JOB         05:00:00                {'NOT_STARTED','RUNNING'}
7               FIN_SIT_BATCH_JOB         11:00:00  {'COMPLETED', 'NOT_STARTED', 'RUNNING'}
```

I tried `df['status'] = sorted(df['status'].values)`, but it didn't work.

Comment: Sets are inherently unordered. Can you convert them to lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set is an unordered kind of collection.

```
df["status"] = df["status"].apply(lambda x: sorted(list(x)))
```